# How to remove one specific element from a list

Tags: python

My variable `L1` looks this:

```
[{'distance': 1.9999,
  'breakEvenDistance': 1.9329,
  'max': 0.0010342833053929787},
 {'distance': 1.9251,
  'breakEvenDistance': 2.0669999999999997,
  'max': 0.0011183923895419084,
  'min': 0.0010342833053929787},
 {'distance': 1.8802,
  'breakEvenDistance': 1.6758,
  'max': 0.0011927892918825562,
  'min': 0.0011183923895419084},
 {'distance': 1.8802,
  'breakEvenDistance': 1.5956,
  'max': 0.0012522046577102665,
  'min': 0.0011927892918825562}]
```

What I need is to remove the last `'max'` in my list! I tried to check the doc, used the function `del` on `L1[-1]['max']` but did not work.. any idea or clue? thanks!

Comment: Can't reproduce, works just fine.

Comment: works just fine del L1[-1]['max'] does the job

Comment: Do you want to remove `max` key from every element? deleting last dict max just works fine using `del L1[-1]['max'] `

Comment: @viktor.w it's unclear whether you want to remove the `max` key from the last dict, or the last dict entirely, or something else. If the first, you've had answers. If the second, you can use `lst.pop()` or `del lst[-1]` to remove the last element. If otherwise, you'll need to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

`-1` to get the last element of the `dict`:

```
del dict_[-1]['max']
print(dict_)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[
 {'distance': 1.9999, 'breakEvenDistance': 1.9329, 'max': 0.0010342833053929787},
 {'distance': 1.9251, 'breakEvenDistance': 2.0669999999999997, 'max': 0.0011183923895419084, 
  'min': 0.0010342833053929787}, 
 {'distance': 1.8802, 'breakEvenDistance': 1.6758, 'max': 0.0011927892918825562, 
  'min': 0.0011183923895419084}, 
 {'distance': 1.8802, 'breakEvenDistance': 1.5956, 
  'min': 0.0011927892918825562}
]
```

Comment: This is already tried by OP and already commented by @rachidelkedmiri.